# Notification sent from Cloud Function not recieved by iOS application but test from Firebase Console works

Tags: swift, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I've been struggling to get notifications sent from a Cloud Function to be recieved and displayed on iOS. I've gone through many different tutorials and methods but I must be missing something.

I've verified push notifications are enabled in Xcode along with Background Modes (Background fetch, Remote notifications, Background processing).

I've uploaded the APNs Auth Key to Cloud Messaging in my Project Settings on firebase with the Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1) enabled.

I've set up a Cloud Function which is tied to the firebase project with a Firebase Admin SDK Service Agent.

No errors are being thrown in my Cloud Function which responds to document updates and creation for a collection. It triggers as expected and shows a successful response including a relative path to the message: textPayload: "Successfully sent message: projects/{Project_ID}/messages/1701549315603249"

I'm at my wits end for where this is falling apart because when I attempt to send a message via the Firebase->Messaging->Create your first campaign->Firebase Notification messages (using the same FCM token that's being used in the cloud function) it's successful and I see the test notification on my phone.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my Cloud Function code where I've tried going via gaxios post request as well as directly through admin.messaging:

```
const gaxios = require('gaxios');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

let db = admin.firestore();

const { GoogleAuth } = require('google-auth-library');

async function getAccessToken() {
  const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: './service-account-key.json',
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging',
  });

  const client = await auth.getClient();
  const accessTokenResponse = await client.getAccessToken();
  return accessTokenResponse.token;
}

// onCreate trigger for new messages
exports.onCreateMessage = functions.firestore.document('recent_messages/{messageId}').onCreate(
  (snapshot) => {
      handleNotification(snapshot);
    return handleNotificationPost(snapshot);
  }
);

// onUpdate trigger for message updates
exports.onUpdateMessage = functions.firestore.document('recent_messages/{messageId}').onUpdate(
  (change) => {
      handleNotification(change.after);
    return handleNotificationPost(change.after);
  }
);

// Function to handle sending notifications
async function handleNotification(snapshot) {
  // Fetching the recent message data
  const messageData = snapshot.data();
  const gid = messageData.gid;
  const toId = messageData.toId; 
  const fromId = messageData.fromId;
  const type = messageData.type; 
  const text = messageData.text;

  // Query the 'games' collection
  const gameRef = db.collection('games').doc(gid);
  const gameDoc = await gameRef.get();

  const gameData = gameDoc.data();
  const gameUsers = gameData.gameUsers || [];
  const user = gameUsers.find(u => u.fid === toId);

  if (!user) {
    console.log('User not found');
    return null;
  }

  // Send notification
  if (user.deviceToken) {
    try {
      // Notification details
        const payload = {
          notification: {
            title: "Test Title",
            body: "Test body"
          },
          apns: {
            payload: {
              aps: {
                alert: {
                  title: "Test Title",
                  body: "Test body"
                },
              }
            }
          },
          token: user.deviceToken
        };
      console.log("FCM Token:", user.deviceToken)
      admin.messaging().send(payload)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error);
          });
      console.log('Notification sent to:', toId);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending notification:', error);
    }
  } else {
    console.log('No device token found for user:', toId);
  }
}

// Function to handle sending notifications
async function handleNotificationPost(snapshot) {
  // Fetching the recent message data
  const messageData = snapshot.data();
  const gid = messageData.gid;
  const toId = messageData.toId;
  const fromId = messageData.fromId;
  const type = messageData.type;
  const text = messageData.text;

  // Query the 'games' collection
  const gameRef = db.collection('games').doc(gid);
  const gameDoc = await gameRef.get();

  const gameData = gameDoc.data();
  const gameUsers = gameData.gameUsers || [];
  const user = gameUsers.find(u => u.fid === toId);

  if (!user) {
    console.log('User not found');
    return null;
  }

  // Send notification
  if (user.deviceToken) {
    try {
        const accessToken = await getAccessToken();
        
      // Notification details
        const payload = {
            "message": {
                "token": user.deviceToken,
                "notification": {
                    "title": "New message from ${fromId}",
                    "body": type === "text" ? (text.length <= 100 ? text : text.substring(0, 97) + "...") : "You received an image",
                },
            }
        };
          
        console.log("FCM Token:", user.deviceToken)
        console.log('Access Token:', accessToken);
        const url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{ProjectID}/messages:send';

      // Sending POST request
        const response = await gaxios.request({
            url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{ProjectID}/messages:send',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            },
            data: payload
          });

      console.log('Notification sent to:', toId);
      console.log('Response from POST:', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending notification:', error);
    }
  } else {
    console.log('No device token found for user:', toId);
  }
}
```

In Xcode I'm using FirebaseMessaging and have set a breakpoint in didRecieveRemoteNotification:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult)
                     -> Void) {
        
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        
        // Print full message.
        print("Did receive remote notification: \(userInfo)")
        
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
```

This breakpoint is hit consistently when the notification is sent from the Firebase Console, but not hit at all when sent from the Cloud Function.

In the Cloud Function logs I only see success messages, I'm at a loss for where to look next to troubleshoot this further.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your JSON payload. Can you please try both the `notification` and 'data' objects with your JSON payload?

I assume that your server key is correction as you're saying that you received a success message on the API response.

```
{
    "notification": {
        "body": "Body of Your Notification in data",
        "title": "Title of Your Notification in data",
        "sound": "default",
        "badge": 1
    },
    "data": {
        "body": "Body of Your Notification in data",
        "title": "Title of Your Notification in data",
        "sound": "default",
        "badge": 1
    },
    "to": "c8VA4sYFrrOqqYLskJQHGgia_*************HF_d_eKQ1WG-UtDH43nsdFWknoUX0",
    "priority": "high",
    "content_available": false
}
```

Let me attach `curl` which might be helpful for you to send test notifications through Firebase API.

```
curl --location 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' \
--header 'Authorization: key=AAAAv65PpAk******************Dt9spURCx7jLA42ULO6F3HyDJspk' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "notification": {
        "body": "Body of Your Notification in data",
        "title": "Title of Your Notification in data",
        "sound": "default",
        "badge": 1
    },
    "data": {
        "body": "Body of Your Notification in data",
        "title": "Title of Your Notification in data",
        "sound": "default",
        "badge": 1
    },
    "to": "c8VA4sYFrrOqqYLskJQHGgia_*************HF_d_eKQ1WG-UtDH43nsdFWknoUX0",
    "priority": "high",
    "content_available": false
}'
```

Please don't forget to replace `server-key` and `fcm token` with your actual value.